# llamar una funcion js de otro archivo js

Tags: javascript

como puedo llamar una función que se encuentra en otro archivo JavaScript
por ejemplo esta funcion con los archivos a.js y b.js que se encuentra en la misma carpeta:

archivob.js :

```
function Sumar(num1,num2){
  var resultado= num1 + num2;
     alert(“La suma es: ”+ resultado);
}
```

y archivoa.js :

```
sumar(2,5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para poder realizarlo puedes hacerlo desde 2 frentes

**Como frontend (desde el navegador)**:

```
<script src="archivob.js"></script>
<script src="archivoa.js"></script>
```

De este modo como declaras primero el archivo que contiene a la función; en este caso `archivob.js`, al momento de ejecutar el archivo `archivoa.js` que solo contiene la ejecución de la misma funcionará pues la lectura del código se hace secuencial y ya "conocerá dicha función que mandas llamar"

**Desde el backend(con NodeJS)**

en el `archivob.js` realizas lo siguiente

```
function sumar(num1, num2) {
     resultado = num1 + num2;
    console.log("La suma es: "+resultado)
}
```

Posterior necesitas hacer que se exporte la función declarando un *objeto* asignando una clave a la función *sumar* que estamos exportando que en este caso es el mismo nombre (cabe hacer señalar que la exportación va justo debajo de donde declaras a la función por lo que tanto la función como su exportación van en el mismo archivo)

```
module.exports = {
    "sumar": sumar
}
```

y para el `archivoa.js` haces lo siguiente

```
const operacion = require("./archivob")

operacion.sumar(12, 9)
```

Lo que dará por consola al hacer `node archivoa.js` lo siguiente

> 21

Si notas no use en el segundo escenario el `console.log()` pues el objeto `window` no existe y no aplicaría por eso lo cambié por el ya mencionado.

De hecho usar `alert` generaría un error así

> ReferenceError: alert is not defined